# Does the Rokinon 14mm f/2.8 AF work on the Nikon Z6 with FTZ adapter?

Tags: nikon

Does anyone know if the Rokinon 14mm f/2.8 AF works on the Nikon Z series with FTZ adapter?

Answer (score 2):

**The Rokinon 14mm f/2.8 AF cannot be used on Nikon Z-mount bodies with the FTZ adapter.**

- The FTZ adapter allows Nikon F-mount lenses to be used on Nikon Z-mount bodies.
- The [Rokinon 14mm f/2.8 AF](http://rokinon.com/lenses/auto-focus/14mm-af) is available in Sony E and Canon EF mounts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't mean the AE version rather than AF? The AF version does not exist for Nikon yet (however, expected a native Z-mount Samyang/Rokinon 14mm f2.8 AF to be announced "soon"). The AE version appears to be working with the FTZ adapter, but photos on Flickr indicate that the metadata is not read correctly, which may affect aperture and exposure control as well. Since it is a manual focus lens it will not autofocus anyway.

A TZE adapter is expected next week that will make Sony E-mount lenses (which should include the Samyang/Rokinon 14mm f2.8 AF) work on Nikon Z-mount. However, since it has not been announced yet it is unclear how well it will work.

But to answer the exact question: No, it will not work because there is no AF-version for the F-mount at the moment.